# .Except LINQ does not exclude values while building in MVC, but does in a simple console app. Why?

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

I tried to be detailed in the question headline. Building an app in MVC. I need a way to build an array minus values that are sent to a controller. I am able to easily do this in a simple console app, but the .Except method doesn't seem to function the same when using it in a controller.

I have a static array in small method. I send some values the method and use the Except method to create a new array. Works exactly as it should.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] sublines = new string[] { "BI/PD", "Hired", "PIP", "Medical Payments" };
        results(sublines);

    }

    public static void results(string[] values)
    {
        string[] subLineVales = new string[] { "BI/PD", "Hired", "Non-Owned", "PIP", "Addtl-PIP", "Medical Payments", "UM PD", "UM CSL", "UIM CSL", "Terrorism" };
        int count = subLineVales.Length;


        string[] DifferArray = subLineVales.Except(values).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in DifferArray)
        {
            Console.Write(item);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

The new array excludes values in the "values" array parameter.

Second, I take this same approach and send specific values in an array to an MVC controller.

```
  public ActionResult MyAction(string[] rid, string[] subLineNames, string[] lineGuids, string uniqline, string uniqpolicy, string uniqlinetype)
    {

        string[] sublineArray = new string[] { "BI/PD", "Hired", "Non Owned", "PIP", "Addtl PIP", "Medical Payments", "UM PD", "UM CSL", "UIM CSL", "Terrorism" };
        string[] subLineValues = sublineArray.Except(subLineNames).ToArray(); //Fills array with sublineArray. Doesn't exclude any of the values from the subLineNames array. And Yes, I've checked to ensure string[] subLineNames actually has values.
```

This should work the same way as the console app, but as I stated above, it just doesn't. It just takes the sublineArray values and inserts them all when it should take only those that ARE NOT in the subLineNames array. I've been working on finding different ways around this for days. Haalpp.. this is driving me crazy.

EDIT. Adding some clarification on the subLineNames parameter.

```
//Listen for the MCPD submit button
$('#mcpdSubmit').on('click', function () {
getSublineValues();
});

function getSublineValues() {

var rid = []; //store RID's
var subLineNames = []; //store subLine names
var Guids = []; //store subLine Guids

//find selected checkboxes and push values 
$("table.subLineTable tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('td input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
        rid.push($(this).find('td .mcalRIDS').html());

    if ($(this).find('td input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
        subLineNames.push($(this).find('td .subLineMCAL').html());

    if ($(this).find('td input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'))
        Guids.push($(this).find('td .mcalGuids').html());

});

var ul = $.trim($('#mcUl').text()); //MCAL UniqLine variable
var up = $.trim($('#mcUp').text());

var MCAL = '5cc3cb18-5b52-454d-88c7-2670501946b4';

var div = $('#MCAL').html();

var sendData = JSON.stringify({'rid': rid, 'subLineNames': subLineNames, 'lineGuids': Guids, 'uniqline': ul, 'uniqpolicy': up, 'uniqlinetype': MCAL });
$.ajax({
    url: '/Trucking/MyAction',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: sendData,
    success: function () {
        //alert('success');
        console.log('success');
        $('#MCAL').html(div);
    },
    error: function () {
        //alert('Error');
        console.log('Error');
    }
}); 


 // location.reload();
alert(subLineNames); //I did this to ensure I was getting the correct values. When submitted, all the values come up correctly.
```

Comment: What's in `subLineNames` on MVC? Probably not what you assume. Easy debugging heuristic: Make a list of the things you can't be wrong about. You're wrong about at least one of them.

Comment: Have you checked that the case is the same?  Also watch out for white space and hidden characters that are hard to view when debugging.

Comment: You haven't shown a complete example that reproduces the problem. But the behavior won't change simply because you're using an MVC pattern. `Enumerable.Except()` will return the set difference between two sequences.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'll edit my post so you can see where subLineNames comes from. It's an Ajax POST. The subLineNames values come from selected checkboxes. The exact same way I fill the first parameter, rid. Just differend <td>'s

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou Well, nobody asked where `subLineNames` came from. We asked *what's in it*. Please share the *actual strings* in `subLineNames`. If you can show us the actual strings, that would be great. If the only way you can do that is by sharing your HTML, we'll settle for that. Thanks!

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou It's very frustrating to have to ask for the same information multiple times.

Comment: @Rufus L I'm not sure how to specifically show a complete example that reproduces the problem. I assumed the behavior won't change simply because of using MVC, it was just the only thing that was different. Unless what juharr said above is happening. Maybe I'm getting some whitespace or weird characters in there that's causing an issue

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou Provide a statically initialized array of strings which contains the values that `subLineNames` has when you have the problem. Just like your console example, but with the values that you actually have at runtime in `subLineNames` in the MVC version when it fails.

Comment: If you just initialize/assign `subLineNames` inside the method you've shown, then we can see what the contents are.

Comment: Apologies @Ed Plunkett. I misunderstood what was being asked for. What's in it is any combination of subLineArray chosen from a checklist.

Comment: `subLineNames` doesn't contain the strings you think it does. Use the debugger to find out what's in there. Use the Visual Studio text editor to correct the problem. We can't help you any further with the details because you're unwilling or unable to provide any relevant information.

Comment: You could set a breakpoint inside the `MyAction` method and examine the contents of `subLineNames` in the debugger. You should be able to see where the problem is there. Most likely the strings contain some other content and are therefore not matching the hardcoded strings (and if you can't tell the difference in the results, it's probably some whitespace character).

Comment: That's not at all what I said Ed. I'm saying that the values in subLinesArray is purely to check and create a new array based on what values I am sending to the controller. I.E. string[] subLineNames may contain any combo of the subLinesArray. If you look at the console app. I pass values to the values method that are present in the subLineVales  array. I then create new one using the .Except method and loop through to verify. It works fine. I do the same thing in the MVC controller but yet it doesn't exclude the values I send

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou I've voted to close the question because you refuse to provide enough information to reproduce the issue, even after having been told how to do it.

Comment: It could also be something as simple as a difference in casing between the strings (which is easy to handle), but I'm afraid there's not much more we can do here without seeing the other array.

Comment: @RufusL Think you're definitely right. I'm an idiot and don't know the best method of simply checking values submitted in a controller unless I add a whole bunch of unnecessary code.  So I did the next best thing and checked the console.log on the front side and this is what showed up. (2) ["↵BI/PD                                ", "↵Hired                                "] .. Lots and lots of white space. EDIT after posting this comment I saw that it didn't include all the white space that I see.. dang

Comment: `string[] DifferArray = subLineVales.Except(values.Select(value => value.Trim()).ToArray();`

Comment: @RufusL. That was literally exactly what I needed. IT WORKED! Trimming and removing the white space worked.  I hadn't thought about that happening until it was brought up, so thank you for the patience and help.

Comment: Cool, i'll add it as an answer so you can close out the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have additional whitespace being returned with your strings. One way to handle this on the method-side is to call `Trim` on each item from the incoming list. Additionally, it may be a good idea to use a case-insensitive comparison, depending on the data source:

```
string[] diffArray = subLineVales
    .Except(values.Select(value => value.Trim()), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Really a great help, @Rufus L. Thanks again. I'm working on improving my questions and was stuck on how to get the right info to ya'll. The white space characters were being added when I pushed the names of a selected check box value via a Jquery function. So no wonder in the controller when I was hard checking using the .Except method and creating the array, it just wouldn't work. Thanks again for what probably seems trivial to you, but a good lesson for me.